# Send multiple files with HttpClient

Tags: php, angular

I've got code that successfully sends images to server:

.ts

```
  onFileSelected(event){
    let files = event.target.files;
    const fd = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i];
      fd.append("media",files[i],files[i].name);
    }
    this.httpClient.post("backend/upload.php",fd, {reportProgress:true,observe:"events"}).subscribe((event)=>{
      console.log(event);
    });
  }
```

This is the output inspected in networks tab that confirms that.

```
------WebKitFormBoundarymwsBJvYMYfzWyk4X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; filename="DSC_0905_2.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundarymwsBJvYMYfzWyk4X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="media"; filename="DSC_0905.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundarymwsBJvYMYfzWyk4X--
```

The problem is, that all the images have the same name, which is used to identify them, and therefore I can only access the first one that was uploaded.

For example

.php
...

```
$_FILES["media"] // do something with it
```

...

only access one image.

What do you propose I do differently so that I will be able to access all of them? The number of images that can be sent is flexible.

Comment: You can use the name with square brackets, I think(eg. media[]). But the `$_FILES` structure will be a bit different

Comment: I can't believe this is the first time I hear about this. Thank you so much!

Comment: On a side note, I've read a few book and never came across this. Do you have some literature you would recommend for the ones that reaaaly want to know serverside programming in depth?

Comment: I don't know about any books. The only programming book I ever bought was C#6.0. The PHP manual and PHP-FIG PSR are good references too, other than that I just search or trial and error. Sometimes I look at how a large framework does it. If you are into web app or http request based app, reading the rfc can be helpful too. It defines the http verbs/methods, header and body, types of uri,etc. But mostly you will get it over time and experience.

Comment: Thanks. I do the same, but am unsatisfied with progress. It is so much more effective to get hands on a **high quality** book. Its crazy that you can learn from an author who spent 5, 10 years (and a lot more often) perfecting his craft and is now able to form condensed highly informative sentences.